# How to iterate through rows in Excel and to check multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, sum, iteration

Please help!

I have this problem and I don't know how to do that in Excel... I'm sure there is a way, I would know how to do it in Python for example. I'm also aware that there is a better way to explain my problem, so I apologize in advance... But here is my exact situation.

My table looks like this:

| row | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MATCHING_A | random_jdd | random_sdf | 23 |  |
| 2 | MATCHING_A | MATCHING_B | MATCHING_C | 10 |  |
| 3 | random_ert | random_dca | random_zzc | 7 |  |
| 4 | random_xhg | random_ghd | MATCHING_C | 347 |  |
| 5 | MATCHING_A | MATCHING_B | MATCHING_C | 5 |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  | 15 |

I need it to iterate through rows until it gets to empty row. I would like it to check multiple conditions: If (in current row) there is "MATCHING_A" in column A, AND there is "MATCHING_B" in column B, AND there is "MATCHING_C" in column C, take value from column D and add it to sum in cell E7, which equals 15.

So, let's say the program iterated through first 5 rows. When it got to row 6, which is the first empty row, the loop stopped. It has found all three matching criteria in row 2 and 5, so it took values 10 and 5 from column D and got the sum 15 that is printed in cell E7.

Please, help me! I would appreciate it!

Thanks! :)

It's hard to describe what have I tried... I'm a rookie in Excel.

Comment: No need for coding here.  Just use the formula `SUMIFS`.

Comment: Can you help me do that?

Comment: Is it something you have access to python with? Pandas handles excel well and can certainly do this. In excel you need to build a vbasic macro. This website (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4438-excel-loop-until-blank.html) has info on how to do that. Personally I always choose python when possible.

Comment: Yes as @BigBen Sir, mentioned, `SUMIFS()` or `MMULT()` would work. But can you explain if there is a new rows added after the sixth row, like seventh or eight will the sum be a new one starting from the blank row here, or you just the sum of those only `MATCHING_A`,`MATCHING_B` etc irrespective of empty rows?

Comment: I would use Python and Pandas if it was for my personal needs... But I'm trying to help my wife with her task, and she uses only Excel :-/

Comment: I would do it like this : =SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,"=MATCHING_A",C:C,"=MATCHING_B",D:D,"=MATCHING_C")

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya, there should be a possibilty to add new rows afterwards. That's why I want it to check until it hits an empty row.

Comment: There is no "Add rows" formula. You would simply put this formula at the cell you would like it to display this result. Should you "insert" rows within the data table, it would, naturally, shift down as well.

Comment: Oh then you got your answer from @T.Grandemange that should work. I was thinking of something complicated thing, sum of all matching values grouped by blanks.

Comment: Do you know beforehand the 3 values you are looking for, or want to find matching rows  without knowing the concrete values?

Comment: Black cat, I know the values I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm going to read SUMIFS() and MMULT() documentation and try to figure out some kind of solution! Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally I'd recommend not using whole column references like A:A, B:B, E:E.

Be specific with the ranges:

```
=SUMIFS(D1:D5,A1:A5,"MATCHING_A",B1:B5,"MATCHING_B",C1:C5,"MATCHING_C")
```

If the operator is 'equals', you don't need to place the equals character in the match string in the formula.

Better than this is to covert your data range to a Table. You do this by placing your cursor in the data range and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

[image]

When the data are in a Table, you can go to the Table Design tab of the Ribbon and change the Table name in the Table Name box:

[image]

Giving your data sensible column headers:

[image]

Your formula can be:

```
=SUMIFS(dat[value],dat[category1],"MATCHING_A",dat[category2],"MATCHING_B",dat[category3],"MATCHING_C")
```

[image]

Storing your data in a Table like this has the benefit of automatically expanding the ranges when new data are added.